# Como podría recorrer este vector a la vez que genero números?

Tags: java, array, netbeans, random

Teniendo un vector de 20 elementos generados aleatoriamente, necesito que el numero cargado no sea múltiplo
Lo del vector aleatorio si me funciona:

```
        int vector []= new int[20];

        int i=0;


        // Obtenemos el primer elemento para poder comparar desde el principio
            vector[i] = (int) (Math.random() * (9999 - 1001) + 1001);

        //Luego generamos desde el elemento siguiente
        for (i=1;i<vector.length;i++) {
            vector[i] = (int) (Math.random() * (9999 - 1001) + 1001);
            for (int j=1 ; j<i ; j++) {
                if(vector [i] == vector[j]){
                    i--;
                }
            }
```

Los números si se generan y no se repiten, pero necesito que ademas de eso los números desde la posición 2 no sean múltiplos de su indice, lo cual intente hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
for(i =2; i< vector.length; i++){

        do {
            vector[i]=(int) (Math.random() * (9999 - 1001) + 1001);
            if(vector [i]== vector[j]){

            }
        }while ( vector [i] % i == 0);
```

El problema es que al sobrescribir existe el riesgo que los números se repitan, alguna idea de como podría arreglar esa parte?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te pues crear una función que reciba tú array y el número que acabas de generar y que devuelva un boolean. Compruebas con un if si el número está en el array. Si no está continuas para comprobar que no sea múltiplo del índice.

Primero definimos dos variables, el array y una variable que almacenara los random generados posteriormente:

```
int[] vector = new int[20];
int rdm;
```

Después generamos números que cumplan las condiciones especificadas para las dos primeras posiciones del array:

```
for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
    do{
        rdm = (int) (Math.random() * (9999 - 1001) + 1001);
    }while(contains(vector, i, rdm));
    vector[i] = rdm;                    
}
```

Por último generamos los números para el resto de posiciones del array:

```
for(int i=2; i<vector.length; i++){
    do{
        rdm = (int) (Math.random() * (9999 - 1001) + 1001);
    }while(contains(vector, i, rdm) || rdm%i==0);
    vector[i]=rdm;
}
```

Aquí dejo el código del método que se encarga de comprobar que el número no está contenido en el array, que devuelve true si el número está contenido y false en caso contrario:

```
boolean contains(int[] vector, int n, int rdm) {
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        if(vector[i] == rdm)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Lo ideal es también colocar un ejemplo en código de la explicación

Comment: Cierto, estaba desde el movil y por eso solo comente. Agrego el código ahora que estoy en el pc.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo, tenia esa idea de comprobar los números por separado, pero no sabia como plantearlo, muchísimas gracias

Answer (score 0):

lo ideal sería que crees métodos, como lo mencionó el compañero anterior, yo lo trabajé de la siguiente manera. Espero que esta sea la consulta.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int vector[] = cargarVector();
    mostrarVector(vector);

}

public static int generarNumeroAleatorio(){
    int numero = (int) (Math.random() * (9999 - 1001) + 1001);
    return numero;
}

public static int[] cargarVector(){
    int vector[] = new int[20];
    for (int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {
        vector[i] = generarNumeroAleatorio();
    }
    return vector;
}

public static void mostrarVector(int vector[]){
    System.out.println("Elementos: ");
    System.out.println("No 0 - " + vector[0]);
    System.out.println("No 1 - " + vector[1]);
    for (int i = 2; i<vector.length; i++) {
        int num = evaluarNumero(vector[i], i);
        System.out.println("No " + i + " - " + num);            
    }        
}

public static int evaluarNumero(int elemento, int posicion){
    int numero = 0;
    if (elemento%posicion==0) {
        numero = generarNumeroAleatorio();
    }else{
        return elemento;
    }
    return numero;
}
```

Cualquier consulta me la haces saber, si fuera modificación encantado. Saludos!

Comment: al principio lo había plateado así, pero es medio engañoso cuando tienes 1000 números de rango, al disminuir los números pueden ser múltiplos o iguales a los primeros dos, pero muchas gracias por tu tiempo, me ayudo bastante

Comment: Hola @Christian, tenés un error en tu respuesta ya que nada te asegura que el numero generado en la función evaluar número,  no sea múltiplo del índice, por lo que no cumple con la consigna.